# How to handle Fields on concurrent requests?

Tags: node.js, concurrency, async-await

I am new in NODE-JS, On my NODE-JS API Fields are not reset properly, On the following, I used properties to store the async methods result but face difficulties on concurrent request, sometimes fields are not reset properly, so the program behaves unexpectedly.

How to handle properties on concurrent requests?

```
  let _companyId ;
  let _companyName ;

  let _deals={};
  let _currentPipeline;
  let _currentDealState;
  let _validCounter = 0;
  let _salesPipelineDeal = {};
  let _csAccountDeal = {};
  let _csDealColseDate;
app.post("/progression", async (req, res) => {

try{

  _companyId = req.body.objectId;
  _companyName = req.body.properties.name.value;
  
  _deals= await getCompanyAssociatedDealsDetail(companyId);
  
   let newMergeDeal = await createNewMergeDeal(newMergeDealObj);
   await updatePreviousCSDeal(csAccountDeal.dealId);
   
      _deals={};
      _currentPipeline=null;
      _currentDealState=null;
      _validCounter = 0;
      _salesPipelineDeal = {};
      _csAccountDeal = {};
      _csDealColseDate=null;

   return res.status(200).send("new Merge Deal " + newMergeDeal.dealId);
}
catch(error)
{
}

});
```

Comment: show me `getCompanyAssociatedDealsDetail` , `createNewMergeDeal` , `updatePreviousCSDeal`, are they promise based?

Comment: Yes, They are! All are async methods.

Comment: are you sure?? because this code is correct

Comment: Concurrently When I request the API, it acts unexpectedly, one single or after deploy the first request works perfectly.

Comment: User fields are not reset so the previous value remained and act unexpectedly. It is possible to guide me on how to use fields/property on concurrently requested api.

Comment: why user fields defined out of route?

Comment: Write some functions, stored information used on those functions. As like global variable.

Comment: you should not use global variables in your project, Global variables are used for fixed data, change your manner, I do not know exactly why these values should be stored in global variables?

Answer (score 0):

see the following exmaple

```
let myObj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
};
let objCopy = myObj;
console.log(myObj);    // {a: 1, b: 2}
console.log(objCopy);  // {a: 1, b: 2}
```

a simple copy like that with assignment operator doesn’t create a fresh copy but instead creates a link that points to the myObj (also called as reference), and just watch what happens if we try to assign new value to the copy objCopy

```
objCopy.b = 10;
console.log(myObj);    // {a: 1, b: 10} what! but i never touched it
```

when you use global variable this creates a problem so for copy variable you can use
`Object.assign` or `Object Spread ({...})` or change your approach

Comment: Without global variable need to pass data as method parameters, right? What is the best approach to declare fields/properties and used them in node-js?

Comment: I prefer to use in-memory data structure store, like `Redis` for sharing data between different routes

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, is it possible to share more details?

Comment: first of all I should understand the functions, what does to do?! `companyId` in `getCompanyAssociatedDealsDetail(companyId)` Where did it come from?and `newMergeDealObj` in createNewMergeDeal(newMergeDealObj) too?and `csAccountDeal.dealId` in `updatePreviousCSDeal(csAccountDeal.dealId)` too?

Comment: I don't put my actual code here, it's just a holistic view, Think in this way have some async method with primitive data type as input parameter, have some functions, don't like to pass data as a function parameter, want to use global properties so functions have data just by the name.

Comment: When I worked with in-memory variable/fields API worked perfectly, but when used global variable problems remain. In concurrent request how API handle in-memory fields information?